# Why doesn't my validation for checking if an array (values from text file) contains a specific string

Tags: c#, arrays, validation

So I have used this way of validating an array with values from a text file in another class which works flawlessly. I tried a bunch of different ways but it just keeps on writing the data to the text file even though a username already exists. Every solution I have researched does not work. It's as if the program just skips the if condition containing the username exists. I really do not understand why it does not work. I have tried foreach loops and nothing. I have tried a bunch of different built in array functions with linq and just straight up default functions.  The code for the working class is here:

````
        string username = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;

        UserCredentials myUserLogin = new UserCredentials();
        FileHandler myFileHandler = new FileHandler();
        DataHandler myDataHandler = new DataHandler();

        myUserLogin.UserDetails(username, password);

        string[] lines = myFileHandler.ReadFromFile();

        Login_Form form1 = new Login_Form();
        Register_Form form3 = new Register_Form();
        Main_Form form2 = new Main_Form();

        bool usernameExists = Array.Exists(lines, element => element == myUserLogin.Username);
        bool passwordExists = Array.Exists(lines, element => element == myUserLogin.Password);

        

        if (usernameExists && passwordExists) // this works
        {
            form2.Show();
        }
        else if (!usernameExists || !passwordExists)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("User not found or password incorrect. Register new user?", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {                  
                form3.Show();
            }
            else{}
        }
```
string username = txtRegisterUsername.Text;
            string password = txtRegisterPassword.Text;
            DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler();
            FileHandler FileHandler = new FileHandler();
            UserCredentials myUserRegister = new UserCredentials();
            myUserRegister.UserDetails(username, password);

            string[] lines = FileHandler.ReadFromFile();
            
            bool usernameExists = Array.Exists(lines, element => element == myUserRegister.Username);

            if (usernameExists) //this does not work
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username already exists, please enter another one");
                }
                else if (!usernameExists)
                {
                    string userDetailString = myUserRegister.Username + ' ' + myUserRegister.Password;

                    List<string> userDetailList = new List<string>();

                    userDetailList.Add(userDetailString);

                    FileHandler.WriteToFile(userDetailList.ToArray());

                    Register_Form.ActiveForm.Close();
                }
            }
````

Comment: Set a breakpoint and examine `lines`. Does it contain the username?

Comment: @PoulBak it says the value is null, weird as I have used the same method in another class which works to compare the text box string with the strings in the text file

Comment: Well, now you have the error and can work with that.